# Laravel/Vue image upload i-viewUI

Tags: laravel, vue.js, iview-ui

I'm making an admin dashboard with Laravel and VueJS. I'm trying to upload an image to the database but I can't even get it to load to the page. I'm getting a 404 (Not Found) error and I have no idea why...???

Routes

```
Route::post('app/upload', 'AdminController@upload');
```

Modal Code

```
                <!-- Tag Add Modal -->
                <Modal
                    v-model="addModal"
                    title="Add Category"
                    :mask-closable = "false"
                    :closable = "false">
                    <Input v-model="data.tagName" placeholder="Add Category Name" />
                    <div class="space"></div>

                        <!-- ref="uploads" -->
                    <Upload
                        :default-file-list="defaultList"
                        :on-success="handleSuccess"
                        :on-error="handleError"
                        :format="['jpg','jpeg','png','bmp',]"
                        :max-size="2048"
                        :on-format-error="handleFormatError"
                        :on-exceeded-size="handleMaxSize"
                        :before-upload="handleBeforeUpload"
                        type="drag"
                        :headers = "{'x-csrf-token' : token, 'X-Requested-With' : 'XMLHttpRequest'}"
                        action="/app/upload">
                        <div style="padding: 20px 0">
                            <Icon type="ios-cloud-upload" size="52" style="color: #3399ff"></Icon>
                            <p>Click or drag files here to upload</p>
                        </div>
                    </Upload>                   
                    <div class="image_thumb" v-if="data.iconImage">
                        <img src="/uploads/${data.iconImage}" />
                    </div>
                    <div slot="footer">
                        <button type="default" @click="addModal=false">Close</button>
                        <button type="primary" @click="addTag" :disabled="isAdding" :loading="isAdding">{{isAdding ? 'Adding..' : 'Add Tag'}}</button>
                    </div>
                </Modal>
```

modal script

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            data : {
                catagoryName: '',
                iconImage: '',
            },
            addModal : false,
            editModal: false,
            isAdding : false, 
            isDeleting : false, 
            showDeleteModal: false,
            tags : [],
            editData : {
                categoryName: '',
                iconImage: '',
            },
            index : -1,
            deleteItem: {},
            deletingIndex: -1,
            token: '',
        }
    },
```

Controller

```
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'file' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png'
        ]);
        $picName = time().'.'.$request->file->extension();
        $request->file->move(public_path('uploads'), $picName);
```

The file begins to show in the drag and drop screen for a couple of seconds then it drops the 404 on me. So it seems like its found the image and loading but then fails.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: make sure that the route /app/upload is exist, clear the cache, does the image being uploaded or not, what's the link of your 404 page

Comment: the error is. POST httpL127.0.0.1:8000/app/upload 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: also How do I clear my cache?

Comment: SO I figured it out. I ran the routes and my new route wasn't there. Saved it again and restarted php artisan serve and then checked my routes and it was there and worked. sigh... weird lol

Comment: great to hear it worked, for the future you can clear your cache by using php artisan optimize